# Mongoose sub-schema shows '[object Object]' in document.

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

From a query done with the mongoose api on a Mongodb, I have what appears to be a json object. But...it's not usable as json Object. What is this and how do I make it a usable json object? `JSON.stringify(result)` and `JSON.parse()` are not effective.

```
    Object.keys(models).forEach(function (model) {
        models[model].find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec(
            function (err, result){
            console.log(result);
           ...
```

---

This:

```
[ { _id: 53b6d3629074ad2e59e4be6f,
    timeStamp: Fri Jul 04 2014 16:16:38 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    available: true,
    status: 'n',
    __v: 0,
    metrics: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ] } ]
```

Should look like this:

```
{ timestamp: 1404486663348,
  available: true,
  status: 'success',
  metrics: 
   { '15m': { data: 0.05, type: 'n', unit: 'unknown' },
     '5m': { data: 0.01, type: 'n', unit: 'unknown' },
     '1m': { data: 0, type: 'n', unit: 'unknown' } } }
```

**EDIT**: This is causing a issue where I can not use it correctly as
`metrics: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]` 
is causing
 `TypeError: Cannot read property '15m' of undefined`
 for
`$scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data.`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not usable about it?

Comment: ` metrics: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]`

Comment: That's just an artifact of `console.log`, whose default behavior is to only show up to two levels of an object.

Comment: It's causing `TypeError: Cannot read property '15m' of undefined` for `$scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data`.

Comment: `cpuResult` doesn't appear in your example doc.

Comment: It's there....I just didn't paste all the code to prove it and I also have verified it is good. It's complaining about `Cannot read property '15m'` because of `metrics: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56792/discussion-between-dman-and-johnnyhk).